# Google Maps API v3 - how to realize screen rotation in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, screen-rotation

Are there any guides or tutorials for how to realize screen rotation in android? How to restore center and zoom of the map after rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use Google Maps Android API v2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start It should work faster and be well documented.